# How do I run a test with a Chrome profile(with arg '--user-data-dir') using Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I need to run auto tests with chrome browser profile.
On selenium, I did it this way:

```
    let chromeOptions = new chrome.Options();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/google-chrome/Default");
    let driver = await new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").setChromeOptions(chromeOptions).build();
```

How can I do this using cypress?

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api.html?

Comment: yes, I saw. only I didn't find the profile argument there

Comment: Please include a summary of your research when asking a question. It doesn't mention profile/`--user-data-dir` specifically, but it *does* mention `args`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add module.export before your code with browser profile path.

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
    launchOptions.args.push('--user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/google-chrome/Default')    
})
}
describe('My First Test', () => {
  it('Project', () => {
    cy.visit('https://project.com:8000/login')
    cy.log('successful sign in ')
  })
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work because cypress overrides user-data-dir with its own profile... any ideas?

Comment: @OriolGomez You can use cy.session. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Arguments