# Can I open cypress test in a desired browser session?

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests, bots, cypress

I am new to cypress and I am trying to automate few things; rather than testing. Actually I am trying to make a simple comment bot in a desired website. My problem is that whenever I try to Login with cypress, it wants me to solve recaptcha. I know recaptcha is only meant for human to solve and so I am thinking, I would first login manually myself then run the cypress in that logged in browser session to automate few things; like commenting for example. This one also doesn't seem to possible with the cypress because they mention they clear all the browser session and storage while starting the test. So is there any workaround to it? Or any alternatives?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a test with a Chrome profile(with arg '--user-data-dir') using Cypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65037269/how-do-i-run-a-test-with-a-chrome-profilewith-arg-user-data-dir-using-cypr)

Comment: Since profiling is not possible, you can put a debug point on login step, manually resolve the captcha and then continue to script execution.